# Change caret color not working in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, caret

i try to make memo program using by Java Swing.
Memo program is need to can change caret color when user want
so, i use JTextArea in Java and use 'setCaretColor' method to my purpose
when input text is english caret color change well but, when input text is korean( composed text) caret color change not working...

why occur this situation ??

at below there is my sample code and image.. both same code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextArea Caret Test");
        frame.setSize(250,250);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        area.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
        area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        area.setCaretColor(Color.RED);

        frame.add(area);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

English result:

[image: english result]

Korean result:

[image: korean result]

Comment: I have no issue (obviously using English :P) on MacOS

Comment: It's possible the look and feel doesn't support changing the caret color